# What is the name of the physical quantity which is the gyromagnetic ratio divided by $2 \pi$?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, physical-constants

I am reading Abramowitz and Stegun's *Handbook of Mathematical Functions* and I come across Table $2.3$, Adjusted Values of Constants.

In there we see:

Gyromagnetic ratio of proton: $\gamma$, with value $2.675 196 5 \times 10^8 \ \mathrm {rad \cdot s^{-1} \cdot T^{-1} }$

etc.

Then immediately underneath it:

$\gamma / 2 \pi$, with value $4.257 707 \times 10^7 \ \mathrm {Hz \cdot T^{-1} }$

I have looked up the page on gyromagnetic ratio on the internet, but while some sources reference $\gamma / 2 \pi$, nobody seems to actually explain what it is.

Can anyone tell me what that "reduced" value is called, and what it is used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s the gyromagnetic ratio. In one case in angular units, in the other in cyclic or “lab” units. This is the same as how we use the word “frequency” to refer to both angular and cyclic frequencies. It is an ambiguity in the language, so you just have to check for consistency with your reference if the factor of $2\pi$ matters for what you’re doing.

“Reduced gyromagnetic ratio” is probably an ok name for it by analogy with reduced Planck constant. I don’t think anyone would argue with you calling it that if you explained what it is.

Comment: Thank you, that backs up my hunch. On a par with this, is it common to talk about "cyclic momentum", that is, angular momentum over $2 \pi$? Or is this fuel for another question?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "angular momentum" in contrast to "cyclic momentum". Are you talking about linear momentum $p$ expressed in cyclic or angular units or angular momentum $L = r\times p$ somehow expressed in cyclic or angular units?

Comment: While angular moment is expressed as "per radian", we would say "cyclic momentum" is expressed as "per cycle". What's unclear? Both are a measure of rotational momentum, just that one is measured "per radian" and the other "per cycle".

Comment: Ok so $L / 2\pi = I \omega/ 2\pi = I f$. I’ve never seen that I don’t think but I can think about it more.